# Define register in verilog

Tags: verilog

In an interview for synopsys, I was as how you would define a 32 bit register in verilog.

I had replied:

```
reg[31:0] reg1;
```

But the interviewer said this was wrong. Can anyone please tell me the answer to this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'register'? Do you mean a flip-flop or a reg type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a fair question. The interviewer expected you to produce a behavioural model of a clocked memory element, but didn't say so. You produced a declaration of a variable which is of a 'register' data type. It's pretty clear that, back in the early days of Verilog, this was actually meant to be the same thing as something with a memory, ie. a 'register'. However, the terminology has changed over the years, with a great deal of back-pedalling to try to make it clear that `reg` doesn't imply 'register'.

Comment: So do you mean to say that something like below was expected???
 
always @ (posedge clk) begin
   a <= d;  end

Comment: Yes, `always` etc. Your first answer was interesting, and he should have prompted you at that point. The word 'define' doesn't have any specific meaning in Verilog, while it does in languages like C. If Verilog had a concept of definition and declaration then your answer might arguably have been correct.